# Symfony Exception detected : The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

Tags: php, symfony

The autoloader expected class "Sdz\BlogBundle\Controller\DefaultController" to be defined in file "C:\wamp64\www\Symfony\vendor\composer/../../src\Sdz\BlogBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
500 Internal Server Error - RuntimeException

Stack Trace

```
in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader.php at line 223  -
                        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Trying to autoload a class with an invalid name "%s". Be careful that the namespace separator is "\" in PHP, not "/".', $class));
                    }
                    throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('The autoloader expected class "%s" to be defined in file "%s". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.', $class, $file));
                }
                if (self::$caseCheck) {
                    $real = explode('\\', $class.strrchr($file, '.'));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, I'd like to refer you to the following guide: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you post the name of your class?

Comment: Need the code of the class this error refers to, please post the code of defaultController (filename, namespace etc)

Comment: <?php
// src/Sdz/BlogBundle/Controller/BlogController.php
namespace Sdz\BlogBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class BlogController extends Controller
 {
  public function indexAction ()
  {
  return $this -> render ('SdzBlogBundle:Blog:index.html.twig');
  }
 }

Comment: the code of defaultController

Answer (score 2):

This error happens when you have a class with a name that does not correspond to the filename.

For example:

```
Sdz\BlogBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php
```

Class name:

```
class UserController
```

Comment: I did it and it did not work

Comment: Thanks Gay, I used DeaultController and it work.